# Transformer model is very slow and doesn't predict well

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, transformer-model

I created my first transformer model, after having worked so far with LSTMs. I created it for multivariate time series predictions - I have 10 different meteorological features (temperature, humidity, windspeed, pollution concentration a.o.) and with them I am trying to predict time sequences (24 consecutive values/hours) of air pollution. So my input has the shape `X.shape = (75575, 168, 10)` - 75575 time sequences, each sequence contains 168 hourly entries/vectors and each vector contains 10 meteo features. My output has the shape `y.shape = (75575, 24)` - 75575 sequences each containing 24 consecutive hourly values of the air pollution concentration.

I took as a model an [example](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_transformer_classification/) from the official keras site. It is created for classification problems, I only took out the `softmax` activation and in the last dense layer I set the number of neurons to 24 and I hoped it would work. I runs and trains, but it doesn't do a better job than the LSTMs I have used on the same problem and more importantly - it is very slow - 4 min/epoch. Below I attach the model and I would like to know:

I) Have I done something wrong in the model? can the accuracy or speed be improved? Are there maybe some other parts of the code I need to change for it to work on regression, not classification problems?

II) Also, can a transformer at all work on multivariate problems of my kind (10 features input, 1 feature output) or do transformers only work on univariate problems? Tnx

```
def build_transformer_model(input_shape, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, num_transformer_blocks, mlp_units, dropout=0, mlp_dropout=0):

    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = inputs
    for _ in range(num_transformer_blocks):

        # Normalization and Attention
        x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)
        x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout
        )(x, x)
        x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
        res = x + inputs

        # Feed Forward Part
        x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(res)
        x = layers.Conv1D(filters=ff_dim, kernel_size=1, activation="relu")(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
        x = layers.Conv1D(filters=inputs.shape[-1], kernel_size=1)(x)
        x = x + res

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(data_format="channels_first")(x)
    for dim in mlp_units:
        x = layers.Dense(dim, activation="relu")(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(mlp_dropout)(x)
    x = layers.Dense(24)(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs, x)

model_tr = build_transformer_model(input_shape=(window_size, X_train.shape[2]), head_size=256, num_heads=4, ff_dim=4, num_transformer_blocks=4, mlp_units=[128], mlp_dropout=0.4, dropout=0.25)
model_tr.compile(loss="mse",optimizer='adam') 
m_tr_history = model_tr.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, validation_split=0.25, batch_size=64, epochs=10, callbacks=[modelsave_cb])
```